# Using zip and list comprehension to create a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip, list-comprehension

I have two arrays:

```
a = [0.001,0.01,0.1,1]
h = [2,4,8,16,32,64]
```

And I want to create a dictionary, where the dict keys are a tuple of the values of `a` and `h` and the dict values are an empty list. However, the way I need this done is so that each unique `a` has every value in `h`, with the desired output:

```
 d = {(0.001,2):[], (0.001,4):[], (0.001,8):[], (0.001,16):[], (0.001,32):[], (0.001,64):[],
   (0.01,2):[], (0.01,4):[], (0.01,8):[], (0.01,16):[], (0.01,32):[], (0.01,64):[],
   (0.1,2):[], (0.1,4):[], (0.1,8):[], (0.1,16):[], (0.1,32):[], (0.1,64):[],
   (1,2):[], (1,4):[], (1,8):[], (1,16):[], (1,32):[], (1,64):[]}
```

The problem is, writing it out manually as I have done above is tedious.

Is there anyway to do this, using `zip` or list comprehension? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what you need is not `zip` which doesn't combine your lists but rather `itertools.product` in a dict comprehension:

```
import itertools

a = [0.001,0.01,0.1,1]
h = [2,4,8,16,32,64]

d = {z:[] for z in itertools.product(a,h)}

print(d)
```

result:

```
{(0.01, 2): [], (0.1, 64): [], (0.001, 64): [], (0.01, 64): [], (0.001, 2): [], (1, 4): [], (0.01, 4): [], (1, 64): [], (0.1, 8): [],
(0.01, 8): [], (1, 2): [], (0.1, 32): [], (0.001, 32): [], (0.01, 32): [], (1, 16): [], (0.001, 8): [], (1, 8): [], (0.1, 16): [],
(0.001, 16): [], (0.01, 16): [], (0.001, 4): [], (1, 32): [], (0.1, 4): [], (0.1, 2): []}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds... I would use `itertools.product(set(a), h)` in case there were duplicates in `a`

Comment: yeah (and same for `h`). In that case, it seems that it's not the case: powers of 10 vs powers of 2.

Comment: indeed, same for 'h'